# When I try to import a java based selenium script using the jar file in TOSCA, getting error:System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005):

Tags: selenium-webdriver, import, tosca

When I try to import a java based selenium script using the jar file in TOSCA, getting error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Tricentis.Automation.SpecialExecutionTasks.SeleniumExecution.SimpleProcessHandler.StartProcess(String path, String arguments)
   at Tricentis.Automation.SpecialExecutionTasks.SeleniumExecution.SimpleProcessHandler.RunProgram(String exe, String args, String& processOutput, String& processError)
```

Should I use a `dll` file instead of the jar? If yes, how to extract the `dll` from the eclipse project?

When I try to import a java based selenium script using the jar file in TOSCA, getting the above noted error.